How do I catch return characters when using character-at-a-time BASH builtin read with if or a case statement?
I stumbled across what should be something simple that's turned out to be a brain-teaser. As a not fully accomplished BASH programmer, I naively thought I could read in characters from an interactive terminal window and actually determine what keys were pressed! MOST keys work out just fine, but how to catch "return" is non-obvious.
Here's some sample code to illustrate the question:
   while [ $justRead != "\n" ] ;
   do
      # read -e -s -N 1 justRead
      read -s -N 1 justRead
      case "$justRead" in
         \n | "\n" | \r | "\r" | ^M | '^M')
            echo  "return"
         ;;
         *)
            echo -n "$justRead"
         ;;
      esac
   done

As can be seen, the code has a line using the Readline library and another that does not. The two behave differently but I've not gotten either to work successfully. I'm SURE it's something I'm doing wrong with my match string.
I also noticed that the -s - silent - option appears to be ignored by Readline but not the other library, not that that matters to the question, I was just surprised by that.
OBVIOUSLY I'm missing something here! This just has to be simple, right?
Please! Just fixing the syntax does NOT help educate! Please explain WHY your fix works.

Re ^M, see my comment on these . I think the $'\n' below is the right answer, but if you want ^M processing, I recommend you set up the smallest test possible in a separate test script to get it working. Good luck.

@shellter I WOULD like to write in a way that takes into consideration "portability," and VERY much appreciate the link. But I'd be a LOT happier if someone would explain why the $ in front of the tick-quoted \n works when the double-quoted, NOT dollar-sign prefaced version does not!

[ justRead != "\n" ] passes to the command with name [   the four strings justRead, !=, \n and ] as parameter.  Just try the command printf "%s :: " justRead != "\n" ] to see the effect. Your [ will always evaluate to true, because the string justRead (8 characters) is always different from the string \n (2 characters). You would at least need the content of the variable named justRead on the left (i.e. "$justRead"), and a string consisting of a newline character to the right (i.e. $'\n'), but then you still have to fix the other flaws in the code.

@user1934428 Thanks for being so attentive; I didn't really care about that particular while loop other than to just keep looping. And yeah, left out that pesky dollar sign!  I was focused on the case statement. ... I would NEVER have thought to look to ANSI C quoting for this. I guess we're just supposed to know BASH follows that standard, probably  because it's well known to programmers. ...I wish I'd have taken BASH more seriously as a programming language back some 30+ years ago when I started using it daily!

@There is nothing related to ANSI C here. Of course, bash has its quoting rules. I am not aware that there would be any "standard" across languages about quoting. In particular, C and bash have fairly different quoting rules. a b or xxx or ' a b' would be valid strings in bash, but not in C. Further, the C string "a\nb" would be syntactically valid in bash, but their content would differ. The so called "ANSI C" quoting mentioned in the bash manual refers solely to the specific $'...'construct. My guess is that, since bash is written in C, they just use sprintf from the C-library.

The solution is to use the ANSI C quoting method that can be found here. The dollar-sign followed by a single-quoted string is a special case, as documented there and is apparently used in BASH.
   while [ justRead != "\n" ] ;
   do
      # read -e -s -N 1 justRead
      read -s -N 1 justRead
      case "$justRead" in
         $'\n')
            echo  "return"
         ;;
         *)
            echo -n "$justRead"
         ;;
      esac
   done


Uh, THANKS, but can you please explain why the dollar sign helps?

OH! The single-quote ALSO matters?! I'd heretofore used single and double, ' and ", interchangeably so long as they're paired! Please clarify!

@RichardT look up the bash manual on "ANSI-C Quoting" ... https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Do ALL the future readers of this the benefit of adding it to your answer, please!
